# Recycler View does not show anything

Tags: java, android, sqlite

These are the classes which I have made

**logcat**

```
11-09 11:34:49.183 27661-27661/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-09 11:34:49.193 27661-27661/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
11-09 11:34:49.197 27661-27661/? V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ce504
11-09 11:34:49.348 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/nischayvaish.com.test1-1/lib/arm64
11-09 11:34:49.360 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-09 11:34:49.463 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-09 11:34:49.484 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 D/AccessibilityManager: current package=nischayvaish.com.test1, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=true, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
11-09 11:34:49.512 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@d00846
11-09 11:34:49.512 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@73d0a07
11-09 11:34:49.593 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ed682f7
11-09 11:34:49.593 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f473564
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
11-09 11:34:49.647 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 E/HAL: PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
11-09 11:34:49.654 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables.
11-09 11:34:49.673 27661-27691/nischayvaish.com.test1 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 01d2d27, I3d52eaf367
                                                                Build Date                       : 12/10/16
                                                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                                Local Branch                     : 
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Reconstruct Branch               : 
11-09 11:34:49.679 27661-27691/nischayvaish.com.test1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-09 11:34:49.679 27661-27691/nischayvaish.com.test1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-09 11:34:49.706 27661-27661/nischayvaish.com.test1 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

This is my **mainactivity** class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tv1;
private RecyclerView recycler_view;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<IncomingNumber> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyTxt);
    recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recycler_view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    readFromDb();
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            readFromDb();
        }
    };

}

private void readFromDb() {
    arrayList.clear();
    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.readNumber(database);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String number;
            int id;
            number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER));
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            arrayList.add(new IncomingNumber(id, number));
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recycler_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DbContract.UPDATE_UI_FILTER));
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

**DbHelper.class**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "numberDb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DbContract.TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER + " TEXT);";
private static final String DROP_TABLE = "drop table if exists " + DbContract.TABLE_NAME;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void saveNumber(String number, SQLiteDatabase database) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER, number);
    database.insert(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public Cursor readNumber(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String[] projection = {"id", DbContract.INCOMING_NUMBER};
    return (database.query(DbContract.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

On compiling code ,it compiled but it does not show any incoming call number.
currently I am beginner in Android So I did not understand the error properly.
Warning given by the application at the compile time,

> Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView

**Phone permission is allowed.**

Answer (score 0):

can't write comment because my reputation but try to Toast array size after readFromDb() and Toast adapter count and recyclerview childCount to check if it really add the data to adapter and recyclerview or not

and try to delete recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true); and let me know if it work or not